# Databases going in recovery mode

Tags: sql-server

I am in a weird problem. Firstly some information about our env.
We have around 50-55 servers and around 100 instances on them.
Backups are configured through netback and that is using `Nt Authority\System` account.
Everything is fine for the 99 instances but in one whenever we enable this account to login some databases go in recovery state.
And when we disable the account than we can recover it with normal restore with recovery.

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Start with the error log.

Comment: In error log it's saying: FCB open failed: could not open file "\\sharepath" for file number 1 OS error: 32 the process cannot access the file as it's being used by another process.

Comment: Can you make sure SQL Server database files and folders are not under AV scanning ?. Or just stop the AV and see if you still face the issue

Comment: Database files are on a share path. And I don't think AV can lead to such problem as in my case. And yes one more thing it's a shared server with more instances and all other are running fine.

Comment: What is the version of that instance?

Answer (score 1):

> In error log it's saying: FCB open failed: could not open file
>   "\sharepath" for file number 1 OS error: 32 the process cannot access
>   the file as it's being used by another process

System account has issues with accessing database files on network share

Can you, perhaps, try this?:

1. grant full access of [domain\serverName$] to
   \\sharepath\sharefolder where database files resides
2. trace if there any open handles to those file, that prevents database to be started

Comment: For finding open file handles, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: The service account is already having complete access to the share path. I am not able to understand how can enabling a account to login can lead to such a problem. Everythings running fine, you enable the login and bang you have some databases in recovery state. Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @user148074, are your databases set to autoclose? Check sys.master_files to verify you don't have different databases using the same physical files.

Comment: Checked and found that auto close is indeed switched on, can this lead to such issue?